# How to preventDefault action with onEnter hook and $transition$? (new ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router [1.0.0-alpha.5](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.5/). Old events are [deprecated there](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.3/modules/ng1_state_events.html#_statechangestart).

so I'm trying to convert

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', ($event) => {
  //some logic
 $event.preventDefault();
});
```

into:

```
$transitions.onEnter({}, ($transition$) => {
  //...
});
```

how could I **prevent default action** from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer:

```
$transitions.onEnter({}, ($transition$) => {
  return $q.reject()
});
```

i.e. you need to return **rejected promise**.

Comment: Why the $ suffix (as well as prefix) to transition parameter? I've seen this elsewhere as well but have been unable to find out its meaning.. thanks